# 'this' - how to use it correctly?

Tags: javascript

I was searching through multiple answers to a classic newby topic: 
How do I change 'anything' with javascript by clicking 'something' in a html-page?

Most answers I found are bound to these 2 answers:

- use onclick within the triggering element and then trigger a function
- use something like getElementbyID and then either trigger a function
  or directly the code

These solutions work really well in a demonstration but in any step further they don't help me anymore. If I for example have multiple elements where I want to toggle the classname

```
<ul id="the_target">
<li>xyz></li>
<li>abc</li>
....
```

I could surely do something like that or similar

```
 function toggleSomething() {
     document.getElementById("the_target").className += " newclass";
}
 window.onload = function () {
     document.getElementById("the_trigger").addEventListener('click', toggleSomething);
}
```

But if target and trigger are the same and not identifiable with an ID-name - what would I do then? Like in that scenario any li-element within the ul#the_trigger.
I know I can use 'this' in a way, but how exactly would I do it in that given scenario instead of

```
document.getElementById("the_target")
```

and

```
document.getElementById("the_trigger")
```

Comment: This comes up a lot with delegrated events. I find the best way to think about it is the `target` is the thing on which the event occurs, the trigger is the thing listening for that event. Say I'm listening for clicks on the entire document, that's the trigger. I click a single button somewhere in the html, that's the target (`event.target`) and usually what you want.

Comment: `.className += " newclass";` is wrong way to toggle class, this keep adding same class to single element. To toggle class you use `.classList.add('newClass')` and `.classList.remove('newClass')`

Comment: @SameerKhan Sorry you're right. I just copypasted something existing. But the question is something else: "...if target and trigger are the same and not identifiable with an ID-name - what would I do then?"

Comment: @Gavin Could you explain that maybe in an example? This whole trigger/target-concept seems to be clear to me, but I have no clue how to really use it for something "realworld"-like

Comment: @SameerKhan classList.toggle("class") is even better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should highlight the difference. Note that if you click inside container but not in a button, then event.target is the same div as the one we attached the listener to (so innerText returns ABCD)

Be aware that some events 'bubble' up through the DOM. If that happens your event's *current* target can be accessed with `event.currentTarget` instead.

```js
document.getElementById('container').addEventListener('click', function(event){
    console.log('a click has happened somewhere on or in "container"');

    var the_clicked_target = event.target; // the thing that was clicked
    var the_listening_element = this; // the div we attached the listener to

    console.log('I am button:' + event.target.innerText);
    console.log(the_listening_element);
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <button>A</button>
    <button>B</button>
    <button>C</button>
    <button>D</button>
</div>
```